# How to add on last string comma in list?

Tags: java

I have this part of code:

```
 if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(itemAttValues)) {
            return String.join(";", itemAttValues);
        }
```

and i get this : `9000;9001` but what i want is `9000;9001;` so on last string to add `;` also.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `String.join(";", itemAttValues) + ";"`

Comment: "Problem is when in list is only one item then i get two commas if i use this" then your list doesn't have just 1 item.

Comment: Updated my answer to account for your array/List only having a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you are working with an array or a ArrayList/List.

For an array:

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(itemAttValues)) {
    if (intemAttVallues.legnth != 1) {
        return String.join(";", itemAttValues) + ";";
       }
    return itemAttValues[0] + ";";
    }
```

For a ArrayList/List:

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(itemAttValues)) {
    if (intemAttVallues.size() != 1) {
        return = String.join(";", itemAttValues) + ";";
       }
    return itemAttValues.get(0) + ";";
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to handle the length/size == 1 case separately?

Comment: You are welcome to improve upon my answer.

Comment: No, I don't want to do something that conflicts with your [deliberate intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902793/how-to-add-on-last-string-comma-in-list/69902845?noredirect=1#comment123567042_69902793). I'm asking you: why do you think that's necessary?

Comment: Submit an answer so I may see what you are talking about.

Comment: https://ideone.com/hrGnXH shows it's the same with and without the special case.

Comment: I see now. String.join takes each value of itemAttValues and builds a string. By taking each value and adding ";" afterwards. If itemAttValues only has 1 value than you don't want to do String.join(";", itemAttValues) + ";". Because the result be string;; (with two semicolons.)  So if itemAttValues only has one value it's get that one and only value and adds one ";" by itemAttValues.get(0) + ";"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JDK 1.8, you can use the `java.util.stream.Stream` combined with the `java.util.StringJoiner` as follows:

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(itemAttValues)) {
    return itemAttValues.stream()
        .collect(() -> new StringJoiner(";", "", ";"), StringJoiner::add, StringJoiner::merge)
        .toString();
}
```

### EDIT (per @saka1029 deleted shortcut):

You can use the `Collectors#joining` utility collector directly:

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(itemAttValues)) {
    return itemAttValues.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.joining(";", "", ";"))
        .toString();
}
```

Comment: Or `.collect(Collectors.joining(";", "", ";"))`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I’d describe your requirement is that you want a semicolon *after each value* rather than just semicolons between them. The separator that a join operation can use is for putting a separator only between the values, so I don’t want to use that one. I prefer to make explicit that I put a semicolon after each value:

```
    List<String> itemAttValues = List.of("9000", "9001");
    String joined = itemAttValues.stream()
            .map(v -> v + ';')
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
    System.out.println(joined);
```

Output:

> 9000;9001;

A good old loop with a `StringBuilder` can obtain the same (left for the reader).

Edit: if your list has got just a single value, we get a semicolon after that too (not two):

```
    List<String> itemAttValues = List.of("9002");
```

> 9002;

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Collector<CharSequence,?,String> joining(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence prefix, CharSequence suffix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> itemAttValues = List.of("9000", "9001");
        String joined = itemAttValues.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.joining(";", "", ";"));
        System.out.println(joined);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
9000;9001;
```